# How do I list contents of installer?

Tags: install4j

Can I list the contents of the installer (.exe or .sh) ? The size of the installer jumped over the course of the last few builds and I want to figure out where the increase is coming from.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to list the contents of an installer. I would check the installation directories of an old and a new installation and use a tool like

http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/jdiskreport/

to see where the increase comes from.